# DolphinDB memory management

Tags: memory, dolphindb

My desktop has 32G RAM. I need to work with a 500GB partitioned table in DolphinDB. Each partition is about 200MB. I would like to understand how DolphinDB manages memory if I am doing an operation, say, sum up a column on the entire table. Seems to me that DolphinDB does memory management differently regarding a partitioned table and an unpartitioned table.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, DolphinDB doesn't have to load all data into memory simultaneously when processing a partitioned table. Take your example. There are about 2500 partitions to process and assume your desktop has 8 hyper threads. DolphinDB would load up to 8 partitions to memory and process them simultaneously. That is, the peak memory usage would not exceed 200M * 8 plus some working memory. DolphinDB is a columnar database and it only load necessary column in a partition. So the memory usage is much less than 200M * 8 in your case because the calculation involves only one column.

Let me explain the caching mechanism of DolphinDB as well. After performing the computation on a partition, DolphinDB wouldn't release the cache of the partition from memory immediately. When the memory usage reaches the set limit (set by `maxMemSize`), DolphinDB start evicting cache.